# how to send mail notification in node.js from getting response

Tags: node.js

I want to send the response through mail in table format.
In mail options html I declare the `res.json(streamingTemplate)==` and the following error is returned:

> `Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. at
>   ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11) at
>   ServerResponse.header`

like that i got...

```
var sendStreamingTemplate = function (req, res) {

authToken = req.headers.authorization;
userAuthObj = JSON.parse(UserAuthServices.userAuthTokenValidator(authToken));
var todayDate = new Date();
var expireDate = new Date(userAuthObj.expire_date);
tokenOK = TokenValidator.validateToken(userAuthObj.user_id, authToken).then(function (userSessions) {
    if (userSessions.length === 1) {
        if (expireDate >= todayDate) {
            StreamingTemplateId = req.params.id;

            TemplateController.findById(StreamingTemplateId).then(function (streamingTemplate) {
                if (streamingTemplate === null) {
                    res.status(404).json({
                        message: 'Streaming not found...'
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log(streamingTemplate);

                    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
                    port: 465,
                    auth: true,
                    active: true,
                    secure: true,
                    requireTLS: true,
                    auth: {
                        user: 'aaaaaaa@domain.com',
                        pass: 'yyyyyyyy'
                            }
                        });

                    let mailOptions = {
                    from: 'aaaaaaa@domain.com',
                    to: 'bbbbbbbbb@domain.com',
                    subject: 'mail notification Test',
                    text: 'Hello !!!!!!!!!everything works fine',
                    html:res.json(streamingTemplate)// i want to send whatever response get i will send to through mail in table format
                        };

                    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
                    if (error) {
                         return console.log("mail not sent" +error.message);
                            }
                        console.log('success');
                        });

                    switch(streamingTemplate.template_name.toString().toLowerCase()){
                           case "stream":
                            res.json(streamingTemplate);
                            break;
                           case "broadcaster":
                            res.json(streamingTemplate);
                            break;
                           case "product":
                           res.json(streamingTemplate);
                            break;
                           default:
                           res.json(streamingTemplate);
                             break;
                       }
                }
            }).catch(function (err) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'something went wrong...'
                });
            });
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Not Authorized...'
            });
        }
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Token Expired...'
        });
    }
}).catch(function (err) {
    res.status(401).json({
        message: 'Token Expired...'
    });
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The res.json() method is a terminal method, which ends the response writing the json specified in it. Therefore, while configuring the **mailOptions**, it should not be used.

```
let mailOptions = {
          from: 'aaaaaaa@domain.com',
          to: 'bbbbbbbbb@domain.com',
          subject: 'mail notification Test',
          text: 'Hello !!!!!!!!!everything works fine',
          html: res.json(streamingTemplate) // Response should not be sent here
        };
```

Instead, the streamingTemplate should be passed to the **html** argument of **mailOptions**.

```
let mailOptions = {
          from: 'aaaaaaa@domain.com',
          to: 'bbbbbbbbb@domain.com',
          subject: 'mail notification Test',
          text: 'Hello !!!!!!!!!everything works fine',
          html: streamingTemplate // set the template here
        };
```

Comment: is any other idea for this one

Comment: any other method is there to send notifications getting response from mysql and the notification in html table format

Comment: i want to send mail notification response from db and that response will set in table format then send using the same credentials

Comment: @umaraja have updated my answer. Note that, response.json() method is somewhat equivalent to res.send() and you cannot modify the response or send it again once it has been sent.

Comment: i tried this again it gave error like mail not sentInvalid non-string/buffer chunk

Comment: let mailOptions = {
          from: 'aaaaaaa@domain.com',
          to: 'bbbbbbbbb@domain.com',
          subject: 'mail notification Test',
          text: 'Hello !!!!!!!!!everything works fine',
          html: streamingTemplate 
        };

Comment: let mailOptions = {
        from: 'uma.raja@ttttt.com',
        to: 'uma.raja@tttt.com',
        subject: 'mail notification Test',
        html:'<table><tr><th>templatename</th><th>description</th><th>templatecontent</th><th>active</th></tr></table>'
                }; like also i tried

Comment: how to use that respone in html

Comment: hoe to declare template here

Comment: If your TemplateController is returning buffer data through "findById" method, then you must atfirst convert it to string before setting the html. Calling simply streamingTemplate.toString() might do the trick. Depends on how exactly you are getting the streamed response

Comment: in mail i am getting "[object SequelizeInstance:notification_template]" not the exact output

Comment: let mailOptions = {
          from: 'aaaaaaa@domain.com',
          to: 'bbbbbbbbb@domain.com',
          subject: 'mail notification Test',
          text: 'Hello !!!!!!!!!everything works fine',
          html: // here i want to create table it shows syntax error in<html> like shows
        };

Comment: @umaraja. Seems like the answer solved the original error mentioned in the question. Can u upvote the answer and set it as accepted answer?